# two users data automatically mixed while updating their details

Tags: asp.net

When two users are updating their property details that time their property information are mixed and stored in database.

I have checked source code as well as stored procedure but could not find any solution.

Comment: Please post your code and provide more details so that we can figure out the problem.

Comment: @Akhtar: which code should i post?   update click event code or stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have proper rollback procedures...  if your database is being accessed in a way that users data is being overwritten you basically need to code your query algorithms or stored procedures better to account for it.

Such as...

//submit data

//check data

//loop
//if not (data) {rollback()}

// submit data

// repeat loop until data is submitted successfully

I've noticed in the code I've looked at that most programmers don't account for this.

I've also noticed that sometimes the data for two seperate records gets assigned the same ID, causing this merging of data

IF I'm way off, sorry, may not have understood the question.

Also, maybe your code that is inserting the data is not functioning properly, so yeah,  some of that code would help, as the other guy said.  Thanks

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Brain:"I've also noticed that sometimes the data for two seperate records gets assigned the same ID, causing this merging of data" you understood right. so what should i do now?

Comment: @Brain: you told as written above is right. cause of merging data.  but i have coded with right session.

Comment: @bhargav I'm guessing you aren't using auto-increment fields in your database? Even if you don't, you can write your inserts to prevent this problem.

Comment: @Brain: i have used auto increment functionality in my database field.